# My component that's supposed to show/hide when a button is clicked is not rendering on click

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I have a course page with a list of students as buttons. On click, the button should render ShowStudentInfo but my ShowStudentInfo component is not rendering on click when nested inside (if state.isClicked). Outside of the the conditional it works fine but I need that conditional otherwise everything will show up on course page render.

Main Course Component

```js
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../actions/index';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import ShowStudentInfo  from '../ShowStudentInfo/ShowStudentInfo'

class CoursePage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      course: {},
      student: {},
      isClicked: false
    };
    console.log(this.props.match.params.cuid)
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this)
  }

  onClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log(this.state.isClicked)
    this.setState({
      isClicked: !this.state.isClicked
    })
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(actions.getCourse(this.props.match.params.cuid));
    this.props.dispatch(actions.getStudents());
  }

  render() {
    let studentList = this.props.student
    const students = Object.keys(studentList).map(student => studentList[student])
    const currentStudents = students.map(student => {
      if ((this.props.match.params.cuid) == student.courses) {
        return (
          <p>
            <button className="students" id={student._id} onClick={this.onClick}>{student.firstName} {student.lastName}</button>
          </p>
        )
        if (this.state.isClicked) {
          return (
            <div className="student-info">
              <ShowStudentInfo firstName={student.firstName}
              lastName={student.lastName} phoneNumber={student.phoneNumber} />
        </div>
      )
        }
      }
    })
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.course.name}</h1>
        <Link to={`/addStudent/${this.props.match.params.cuid}`}> Add a new student</Link>
        <div className="studentList">Your students{currentStudents} </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  return {
    course: state.course.course,
    student: state.student.students
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CoursePage)
```

My ShowStudentInfo component

```js
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../actions/index';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class ShowStudentInfo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      student: {
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        phoneNumber: ''
      },
      isClickedEdit: false,
      isClickedDelete: false
    }
    this.isClickedEdit = this.isClickedEdit.bind(this)
    this.isClickedDelete = this.isClickedDelete.bind(this)
  }
  isClickedEdit(event) {
    this.setState({
      isClickedEdit: true
    })
  }
  isClickedDelete(event) {
    this.setState({
      isClickedDelete: true
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="student-info-container">
        <p>Name: {this.props.firstName} {this.props.lastName}</p>
        <p>Phone Number: {this.props.phoneNumber}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

```
if (this.state.isClicked) {
      return (
        <div className="student-info">
          <ShowStudentInfo firstName={student.firstName}
          lastName={student.lastName} phoneNumber={student.phoneNumber} />
    </div>
  )
    }
```

is the most important part to look at and the info is rendering normally without the onClick conditional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your map function contains 2 return functions, while the first return will cause it to go to the next item in the current iteration process

```
if ((this.props.match.params.cuid) == student.courses) {
    return (
      <p>
        <button className="students" id={student._id} onClick={this.onClick}>{student.firstName} {student.lastName}</button>
      </p>
    )
    // this will never hit in case the previous statement is evaluates to true
    if (this.state.isClicked) {
      return (
        <div className="student-info">
          <ShowStudentInfo firstName={student.firstName}
          lastName={student.lastName} phoneNumber={student.phoneNumber} />
        </div>
        )
    }
}
```

To achieve what you want to do, (i am guessing you wish it as part of the first return statement), you could do it like so

```
if ((this.props.match.params.cuid) == student.courses) {
    return (
      <p>
        <button className="students" id={student._id} onClick={this.onClick}>{student.firstName} {student.lastName}</button>
        { this.state.isClicked && <div className="student-info">
          <ShowStudentInfo firstName={student.firstName}
          lastName={student.lastName} phoneNumber={student.phoneNumber} />
        </div> }
      </p>
      )
}
```

Be warned: This will show the students info as part of the `p` tag for all the students on the screen, I don't see where you restrict showing the users info for the one clicked student.

As another side note, are you sure you wish to comparse an object of courses with a cuid parameter?

Comment: thank you just one more question. Now all of the students are showing up under the button instead of all of them. How can I have it show up for just one? In regards to your courses question, that is actually the id of the course. I am storing a course's ID inside of a student object to check if a student is within a course. That's poor syntax/naming on my part and I'm going to change it later.

Comment: Why not make the button part of the `ShowStudentInfo` or create an extra `ToggleStudentInfo` component that handles its own state so you can do it per student (so it would then render the button, manage the state, and render ShowStudentInfo, per student)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a little refactoring in your logic :) hope it helps you.

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../actions/index';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import ShowStudentInfo from '../ShowStudentInfo/ShowStudentInfo'

class CoursePage extends React.Component {

  state = {
    course: {},
    student: {},
    isClicked: false
  };

  onClick = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log(this.state.isClicked)
    this.setState({
      isClicked: !this.state.isClicked
    })
  }

  getCurrentStudents = (students) => {
    const { match } = this.props
    const { isClicked } = this.state

    return students.map(student => {
      if (match.params.cuid == student.courses) {
        return (
          <div>
            <p><button className="students" id={student._id} onClick={this.onClick}>
              {student.firstName} {student.lastName}
            </button></p>
            {isClicked && this.getStudentInfo(student) }
          </div>
        )
      }
    })
  }

  getStudentInfo = (student) => (
    <div className="student-info" >
      <ShowStudentInfo
        firstName={student.firstName}
        lastName={student.lastName}
        phoneNumber={student.phoneNumber} />
    </div>
  )


  componentDidMount() {
    let { match, dispatch } = this.props
    dispatch(actions.getCourse(match.params.cuid));
    dispatch(actions.getStudents());
  }

  render() {
    let { studentList, match, course } = this.props
    const students = Object.keys(studentList).map(student => studentList[student])
    const currentStudents = this.getCurrentStudents(students)

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{course.name}</h1>
        <Link to={`/addStudent/${match.params.cuid}`}> Add a new student</Link>
        <div className="studentList">Your students{currentStudents} </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  return {
    course: state.course.course,
    student: state.student.students
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CoursePage)
```